# Add NSBezierPath to NSView, in order to add a subView to NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Whenever I try to create a line using NSBezierPath, it will never show. However, I know that if I were to add that line to a view and add that view to the window, it would work.

Note: I'm doing this **Programmatically, not with XCode**

If anyone could help that would be great.

```
@interface WindowView : NSView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;

@end

@implementation WindowView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

@end
```

Then I call it by:

```
[[WindowView alloc] drawRect:[window->handle frame]];
```

Note: window->handle is an instance of NSWindow, and if you were to log it, frame is an NSRect

Comment: You need to override the DrawRect method on a custom NSView. You should see examples if you look around here.

Comment: I've tried that, however when I try to add the view, it is an incompatible type after drawing the rect out of the custom NSView, and even when I manage to get past that, the rectangle still fails to show.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Edited my question. And I know I can init a view with a rect, and change the background color, but I want to do more than just a rectangle (Like NSBezierPath, NSBox, etc.)